# Microsoft SharePoint (android/iOS) App do not respect hiddens fields in list

Tags: sharepoint-online, app

First off in the following when I mention "app" I'm specifically talking about the app for Android/iOS from Microsoft ([Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.sharepoint&hl=da)) - I'm not talking about any app I have created, any "app" within SharePoint or anything else. With that out of the way here's my source of frustration:

I have a list containing a lot of fiels. Some of those fields I don't want the users to touch (As they are used in my workflow), so I've turned on content type and removed them. Now enter the SharePoint app - and lo and behold some of those 'removed' fields are fully editable from within the app.

What I find deeply frustrating is that it's not all the fields, that are hidden from the view which is present in the app.

One of the fields I did hide from view a few hours ago, so one thesis would be that the app simply are using some form of cached view of the rule.

Has anybody seen similar behaviour?

Comment: How have you "hidden" those fields? Have you set the flags to display in display/edit/new forms to false?

Comment: They are hidden from the content type setting, some are removed others are hidden. Hover I tried reinstalling the app and now all hidden fields are hidden, so it could be a cache issue.

Comment: Ok, good... Just remember that even if they are hidden, they are still there and you can access them. So don't put anything in there that you don't want the users to figure out.

Comment: Yeah i know that - it's not anything secret, just records of status fields to be able to trigger workflows whenever status is changed. It would derail the workflow if the users mistakenly would edit it. IF they deliberately look for it and do edit it then it's a job for their manager to handle that :D

Comment: I just hate security by obscurity ;)

Comment: Yup that really doesn't work unless the users a digital neanderthals :-D

Answer (score 0):

It seems the list of fields are cached in the app. As long as somebody doesn't change the field visibillity it will be ok.